# Not able to access sharepoint site from France

Tags: user, access, login, intranet, cross-domain

Our sharepoint site is not external facing site and was able to access through intranet by all France users and other countries users. But since Yesterday all french users have no access to the sharepoint site.

The site is hosted in UK, and its able to access by Holland,Spain and etc users but,except french users.

Domain Trust is already in place. The users are able to access the site (http://intranet), but not automatically logged in. Even when providing the login details, users are not getting logged. it is a critical problem that i need to solve ASAP.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Online forums are not the best place to get help resolving critical issues!
You should be asking yourself these questions:

-When did the problem start

-Did it coincide with other work

-What authentication is being used

-What's different in locations where it works

And taking these actions:
-Confirm there were no browser updates, zone changes etc

-Check IIS logs to confirm the sub-status of the 401

-Capture a network trace. If you are unable to read it find a resource to help you.

Comment: No changes were made in the environment. it just happened suddenly